# Div text not showing up with Selenium Python

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver

I"m putting together a webscraper to collect locational data for Goodwill stores based on a list of zipcodes. I have done this multiple times in the past for other stores but Goodwill's website seems to be a little different. Here is how the div that I'm trying to scrape is set up.

```
<div class="contact">4300 W 36 1/2 St<br>St Louis Park, MN 55416<br><div 
 class="phone">(952) 922-9640</div><a onclick="ga('send', 'event', 
 'Locator', 'Clicked Location Website Link', 'http://www.seconddebut.org');" 
 class="website" href="http://www.seconddebut.org">Visit Website</a></div>
```

From this div I want to scrape the street address, city, state, & zipcode. I have tried this code

```
htmlSource = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlSource, 'html.parser')
stores = soup.find("div", attrs={"class":"contact"})
for store in stores:
    print store.get_text()
```

I have also tried this

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlSource, 'html.parser')
stores = soup.find("div", attrs={"class":"contact"})
children = stores.findChildren("br", recursive=False)
for child in children:
    print child
```

Neither of these options have worked for me yet. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is this from https://www.goodwilleasterseals.org/shop/find-store? The HTML there doesn't look like this. Since it seems to be a public URL, can you post it?

Comment: Jeff, I've been using this url https://www.goodwill.org/locator/ but it looks like there are the same locations on the url that you've prodived as that one that I've been using. I'm going to try yours

Comment: I still don't see the HTML that you posted. Can you edit your question and put in the step by step instructions of how you would manually get to the results page you are trying to scrape?

Answer (score 0):

Try selenium

```
 webrdriver.find_element_by_ccs_selector('selector path').text
```

Comment: Have you tried different browsers with selenium? Sometimes this help. Check phantomjs too

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they all follow the same pattern, something like the below should work:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

markup = r"""
<div class="contact">4300 W 36 1/2 St<br>St Louis Park, MN 55416<br><div 
 class="phone">(952) 922-9640</div><a onclick="ga('send', 'event', 
 'Locator', 'Clicked Location Website Link', 'http://www.seconddebut.org');" 
 class="website" href="http://www.seconddebut.org">Visit Website</a></div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(markup, "html.parser")

store = soup.find("div", attrs={"class": "contact"})
print(list(store.strings)[:2])
```

Result:

```
['4300 W 36 1/2 St', 'St Louis Park, MN 55416']
```